# Why is Apache Nifi process consumes about 30% CPU resource?

Tags: cpu-usage, apache-nifi

I have only one processor named "GetFile" running on the Nifi flow without any messages being handled, also, there is no error in the nifi-app.log.

However, the Nifi java process consumes about 30% system CPU resource, does anyone know why and how to tune the performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default setting for that processor is overly aggressive and leads to high CPU usage.  Set 'polling interval' to say '1 sec' and that should help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I set it from '60 sec' to '1 sec', the CPU decreases now, but I am still a little confused about this, it seems the processor polls more frequently with '1 sec', how does the CPU decrease? Could you help to clarify this for me?

Comment: And also there are some other Timer-Driven processor like HandleHttpRequest also cause high CPU too, I was wondering if you have any suggestions for this?

Comment: For GetFile the default polling is zero seconds which means it will poll constantly.  Setting it to one second means it will poll no more than once per second.  In both cases when it will actually poll is a function of how often the processor itself is scheduled to execute. If you had it set to 60 secs polling and changed it to 1 secs and saw less CPU usage I cannot explain that without other information about what other changes might have occurred.

Comment: With regard to other processors that are CPU usage the same general pattern will emerge.  Processors can be written in ways that are higher throughput, lower latency, etc..  Those that consume high levels of CPU while idling are likely not taking advantage of simple techniques to improve this and they should be updated as appropriate to tune their aggression levels down and save on CPU.

Comment: For other processors, I changed schedule property of the Processor, and the CPU decreased indeed.

Comment: But for the "GetFile" processor, I am still confused why the CPU decreased from 60 sec to 1 sec with nothing else changed with the default value.